# Mocking problem on Non-Virtual functions with NVI Idiom

Tags: c++, c++20, googletest, googlemock, non-virtual-interface

I followed Herb Sutter's [NVI idiom](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm) on my class design because of its benefits. My abstract class is as follows in short.

```
class Communicator {
public:
    virtual ~Communicator() = default;
    bool Connect(void) {
        // some preoperations
        return DoConnect();
    }
    // 3 more similar public member functions

private:
    virtual bool DoConnect(void) = 0;
    // 3 more similar pure virtual member functions
};
```

I inject Communicator class to the class I want to test as follows (I found this method from [Google docs](https://google.github.io/googletest/gmock_cook_book.html#MockingNonVirtualMethods)) :

```
template <typename CommunicatorClass> // There will be some constraints
class TestingClass {
public:
    TestingClass(std::unique_ptr<CommunicatorClass> comm) : comm_{std::move(comm)} { }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<CommunicatorClass> comm_ = nullptr;
};
```

My Mock class :

```
class MockCommunicator : public Communicator {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD(bool, Connect, ());
    // 3 more mocks
};
```

My Test suite Setup:

```
// some code ..
auto mock = std::make_unique<MockCommunicator>();
TestingClass<MockCommunicator>(std::move(mock));
```

As you can guess since I did not override 4 private virtual functions MockCommunicator becomes abstract and the compiler gives error. Options I thought :

1. Overriding virtual functions in MockCommunicator. (It seems ugly, but I am closest to this approach)
2. I could convert pure virtual functions to virtual functions but I am not the only one who owns the code base. I want to force other developers to implement their own implementation.
3. Making MockCommunicator the friend of Communicator class and mock private virtual functions. ( I think this is absolutely wrong. Is it?)
4. Giving up on NVI because of its complexity to the code base

Is there any recommended way of handling this situation?

Note : I use C++20

Comment: Even tough the question is quite clear, you should fix posted code to compile as-is. Currently you have missing semicolons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of mocking your public `Connect` it would be easier to mock the virtual private `DoConnect` (and all other pure virtual functions of course, it's not ugly, if you mock, you mock all the interface, not a fraction of it):

```
class MockCommunicator : public Communicator {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD(bool, DoConnect, (), (override));
    // 3 more mocks
};
```

Note that in mock `DoConnect` is public so that you can use it in `EXPECT_CALL` macros. Then assuming your `TestingClass` has some simple way to invoke the `Communicator` observable behavior:

```
    bool run() {
        return comm_->Connect();
    }
```

you can write a simple test:

```
TEST(xxx, yyy) {
    auto mock = std::make_unique<MockCommunicator>();
    auto* rawMock = mock.get();
    auto sut = TestingClass<MockCommunicator>(std::move(mock));
    EXPECT_CALL(*rawMock, DoConnect()).WillRepeatedly(testing::Return(true));
    ASSERT_TRUE(sut.run());
}
```

Having that, you don't even need your `TestingClass` to be a template:

```
class TestingClass {
public:
    TestingClass(std::unique_ptr<Communicator> comm) : comm_{std::move(comm)} { }
    bool run() {
        return comm_->Connect();
    }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Communicator> comm_;
};
```

And as a side note, your `class Communicator` must have a virtual destructor.

[godbolt demo](https://godbolt.org/z/EaE5PTs9e)

Comment: I see your point. You are right. I missed that the overridden functions in `MockCommunicator` could be public. In this case I don't event need friendship. Wouldn't skipping pre- and post-conditions wrapping `DoConnect` invite a potential problem in future?

Comment: I can't think of any obvious problems that might appear just because your `Connect` delegates straight to `DoConnect`. However, if that is the case, consider simply making `Connect` public virtual, and drop the rest. Unless you see some non-obvious reasons to keep `Connect` non-virtual.